# How the function dimshuffle works in Theano

Tags: python, theano

I am having tough time understanding what and how [dimshuffle()](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor._tensor_py_operators.dimshuffle) works implemented in Theano? I got the following set of examples in the official documentation but couldn't understand their meaning.

Can anyone explain what each examples mean in the following?

```
(‘x’) -> make a 0d (scalar) into a 1d vector
(0, 1) -> identity for 2d vectors
(1, 0) -> inverts the first and second dimensions
(‘x’, 0) -> make a row out of a 1d vector (N to 1xN)
(0, ‘x’) -> make a column out of a 1d vector (N to Nx1)
(2, 0, 1) -> AxBxC to CxAxB
(0, ‘x’, 1) -> AxB to Ax1xB
(1, ‘x’, 0) -> AxB to Bx1xA
(1,) -> This remove dimensions 0. It must be a broadcastable dimension (1xA to A)
```

Please note, I know about [broadcasting concept in numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) python.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without `'x'`, `dimshuffle` is same as `transpose`

For explanatory purpose, let's fake numpy has a `dimshuffle` function

```
x = np.arange(60).reshape((3,4,5))
x.dimshuffle(0, 1, 2).shape # gives (3, 4, 5)
x.dimshuffle(2, 1, 0).shape # gives (5, 4, 3)
```

Since we have:

```
shp = (3,4,5)
(shp[2], shp[1], shp[0]) == (5, 4, 3)
```

The arguments `2, 1, 0` to dimshuffle just means the **permutation** to the shape tuple.

Whenever there is `'x'` present, it adds 1 sized dimension into the array:

```
x = np.arange(60).reshape((3,4,5))
x.dimshuffle(2, 1, 0, 'x').shape # (5, 4, 3, 1)
x.dimshuffle(2, 1, 'x', 0).shape # (5, 4, 1, 3)
x.dimshuffle(2, 'x', 1, 0).shape # (5, 1, 4, 3)
```

Whenever the permutation is missing an index (or multiple), these indices are removed from shape tuple, provided that they are 1 (which is broadcastable)

```
x = np.arange(1337).reshape(2,1337,1)
y = x.dimshuffle(1,0) # this works since shape[2] is 1
y.shape # (1337, 2)
z = y.dimshuffle(1) # ERROR
```

Note theano has no way to determine the shape of symbolic tensor, so `dimshuffle` with dimensional removal must refer to `broadcastable` attribute. (This is different to tensorflow as you can specify shape at compile-time)

```
>>> x = T.vector()
>>> x.broadcastable
(False,)
>>> y = x.dimshuffle('x', 0, 'x')
>>> y.broadcastable # the new dims are broadcastable because we added via 'x'
(True, False, True)
```

With `dimshuffle`, you can save multiple calls to `transpose` and `expand_dims` (note Theano has no `expand_dims`)